# Cisco 0-day CMP exploit

Tags: cisco, switch, security

Just found today there is a 0-day exploit in many Cisco switch which use `CMP` cluster management protocol which allow remote command execution.

https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/content/CiscoSecurityAdvisory/cisco-sa-20170317-cmp

As per above link when i run this command to check CMP is running or not, its seems its not enable on my switch does that means we are secure?

```
SW1#show subsys class protocol | include ^cmp
SW1#
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the the [Cisco Advisory](https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/content/CiscoSecurityAdvisory/cisco-sa-20170317-cmp):

> Cisco devices running a vulnerable Cisco IOS XE release are affected
>   by this vulnerability when the following conditions are met:
>
> The CMP  subsystem is present on the Cisco IOS XE software image running on the device,
>
> and
>
> The device is configured to accept incoming Telnet
>   connections.
>
> In order to determine if the CMP subsystem is present on
>   the running software image, execute the command show subsys class
>   protocol | include ^cmp from a privileged CLI prompt on the device.
>
> The following example shows the output of the command **show subsys
>   class protocol | include ^cmp** when the CMP subsystem is present on the
>   software image running on the device:

```
 Switch#show subsys class protocol | include ^cmp cmp                  
 Protocol    1.000.001      Switch#
```

> The following example shows the output of the command **show subsys
>   class protocol | include ^cmp** when the CMP subsystem is not present on
>   the software image running on the device:

```
Switch#show subsys class protocol | include ^cmp     
Switch#
```

> In order to determine if the
>   device is configured to accept incoming Telnet connections, execute
>   the command show running-config | include ^line vty|transport input
>   from a privileged CLI prompt. The command output may indicate one of
>   multiple possible configurations, such as the following: The absence
>   of a transport input configuration line after the line vty
>   configuration line indicates the device is using the default set of
>   protocols for incoming connections through a virtual terminal (VTY).
>   The default set of protocols includes the Telnet protocol; hence, this
>   device will accept Telnet connections on all VTYs. This is a
>   vulnerable configuration.

Comment: In my case `CMP` isn't present but `telnet` is enabled default.